# Problem in splitting an input into positions of an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, strtok

I'm learning C and I'm having a problem splitting a string of text.
I want the user to type many words separated by space in one line, then the program will split this words and save each of them in a position of the array named *list*, in order to do this I'm trying to use the *strtok()* function but Im running into some warnings and errors but I can't see what im doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char list[1000];
    char input[1000];


    printf("Type:\n"); //test

    scanf("%1000[^\n]", &input);

    char* split = strtok(input, " ");
    while(split != NULL) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        list[count] = split;
        count++;
        split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", list[0], list[1]); //test




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try an array of *pointers* `char *list[1000];` Compiler warnings are your friend. Aside `scanf("%1000[^\n]", &input);` should be `scanf("%999[^\n]", input);` – that is one character less, and no address-of.

Comment: [stylistic] 1) don't use strtok(), it is terrible. 2) sanitise your loop, don't allow out of bound indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` needs to be an array of `char *`, not an array of `char`.

Change the declaration to:

```
char *list[1000];
```

Also, the initialization `int count = 0;` needs to be *before* the `while` loop. Otherwise you keep setting it back to `0` and replacing the first array element every time.